# PHP variable name concatenation not working

Tags: php

The php variable is not displaying the result.

```
<h2 class="bold"><? echo ${"application->client->s_MEMBERCLUB_STATUS_{$i}_NAME"}; ?>&nbsp;Member</h2>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have php short tags enabled? What happens if you change `<?` to `<?php`?

Comment: First check the above suggestion. Short tags are off as default since a few versions back. Then change your echo to `echo $application->client->{"s_MEMBERCLUB_STATUS_{$i}_NAME"};`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
<?php echo $something; ?>
```

or

```
<?= $something; ?>
```

Which is the shorthand.

If you want to use the original code, although it is discouraged, you can check out how to enable it here:
[PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)